# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ReactiveFormsModule already imported

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have ReactiveFormsModule already imported in shared.module.ts. It is shared across many forms. I am building a new form, but for some reason I am getting this error on this line

```
<form [formGroup]="additionalInterestsForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" class="additionalInterests">
```

I am not sure what I'm missing. My component.ts file successfully imports FormGroup and uses it. I am confident ReactiveFormsModule not being imported is not the issue as many previous answers to similar questions suggest, because I have created two other forms and they work and I never had to import ReactiveFormsModule into any other module since it is already imported in the shared module.

I'm not sure what code I need to show to give a clearer picture.

This is shared.module.ts.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-
spinner';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-
fontawesome';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import {
    fas
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {
    fab
} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import {
    far
} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'



import { BigInputComponent } from './big-input/big-input.component';
import { BigInputActionComponent } from './big-input/big-input-
action.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        TranslateModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatTreeModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatBadgeModule
    ], 
    declarations: [BigInputComponent, BigInputActionComponent],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        TranslateModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        BigInputComponent,
        BigInputActionComponent,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatTreeModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatBadgeModule

    ]
})
export class SharedModule {

    constructor(private library: FaIconLibrary) {
         library.addIconPacks(fas, far, fab);
         //library.addIcons(faBars);
    }
}
```

This is app.module.ts.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-
browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared';
import { SettingsModule } from './settings';
import { StaticModule } from './static';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthService } from './core/auth/auth.service';
import { LoggingInterceptor } from './core/http-interceptors/http-
logging.interceptor';
import { SignalRModule } from 'ng2-signalr';
import { createConfig } from './core/signalr/signal.model';
import { ConnectionResolver } from './core/signalr/signalr.service';
import { HttpErrorInterceptor } from './core/http-interceptors/http-
error.interceptor';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { DynamicModuleLoader } from './dynamic-module/dynamic-module-
loader.module';
import { FormLoginComponent, LoginDialog } from './form-login/form-
login.component';
import { PolicyDialog, FormPolicyComponent } from './form-policy-search/form-
policy-search.component';
import { MenuListItemComponent, NavService } from './menu-tree/menu-list-
item.component';
import { FormInsuredDetailComponent } from './form-insured-detail/form-
insured-detail.component';
import { FormAddressComponent } from './form-address/form-address.component';
import { FormMortgageeComponent } from './form-mortgagee-detail/form-
mortgagee-detail.component';
import { FormCoverageComponent } from './form-basic-coverage/form-
coverage.component';
import { FormRatingComponent } from './form-rating/form-rating.component';
import { FormUnderwritingComponent } from './form-underwriting/form-
underwriting.component';
import { FormAdditionalInfoComponent } from './form-additional-info/form-
additional-info.component';
import { FormCancellationComponent } from './form-cancellation/form-
cancellation.component';
import { FormReinstatementComponent } from './form-reinstatement/form-
reinstatement.component';
import { QueueCartComponent } from './queue-cart/queue-cart.component';
import { PolicyConfirmationDialog } from './form-policy-search/policy-
confirmation-dialog/policy-confirmation-dialog.component';
import { SubmitedMenuComponent } from './submited-menu/submited-
menu.component';
import { SubmitedDetailsDialog } from './submited-menu/submited-details-
dialog/submited-details-dialog.component';
import { FormMicComponent } from './form-mic/form-mic.component';
import { FormCommentComponent } from './form-comment/form-comment.component';
import { QueueCartConfirmationDialog } from './queue-cart/queue-cart-
confirmation-dialog/queue-cart-confirmation-dialog.component';
import { QuestionService } from './dynamic-
module/questions/service/question.service';
import { QuestionControlService } from './dynamic-
module/questions/service/question-control.service';
import { FormAdditionalInsured } from './form-additional-insured/form-
additional-insured.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [



         // angular
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,

         // core & shared
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule,
         // features
        StaticModule,
        SettingsModule,

         // app
        AppRoutingModule,
        SignalRModule.forRoot(createConfig),
        DynamicModuleLoader,
    ],
    declarations: [
         AppComponent,
         FormLoginComponent,
         FormPolicyComponent,
         LoginDialog,
         PolicyDialog,
         PolicyConfirmationDialog,
         MenuListItemComponent,
         FormInsuredDetailComponent,
         FormAddressComponent,
         FormMortgageeComponent,
         FormCoverageComponent,
         FormRatingComponent,
         FormUnderwritingComponent,
         FormAdditionalInfoComponent,
         FormAdditionalInsured,
         FormCancellationComponent,
         FormReinstatementComponent,
         QueueCartComponent,
         SubmitedMenuComponent,
         SubmitedDetailsDialog,
         FormMicComponent,
         FormCommentComponent,
         QueueCartConfirmationDialog
    ],
    providers: [AuthService, HttpErrorInterceptor, LoggingInterceptor, 
    ConnectionResolver, NavService, QuestionService, QuestionControlService],
    //QuestionService,QuestionControlService remove after demo
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [LoginDialog, PolicyDialog, PolicyConfirmationDialog, 
    SubmitedDetailsDialog, QueueCartConfirmationDialog]
})
export class AppModule {

     //constructor(private _signalR: ConnectionResolver) {

    //}
}
```

component

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit, Output, Input, 
EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicComponentBase } from '../../dynamic-component-base';
import { ROUTE_ANIMATIONS_ELEMENTS, AppState } from '../../../../core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AdditionalInterestsFormModel, AdditionalInterestsFormElements } from 
'../../../../core/store/forms/additional-interests/additional-interests-
form.model';
import { selectLoadingAdditionalInterest, selectPolicyIsReadOnly, 
selectIsAdditionalInterestsInCart, selectIsAdditionalInterestsSubmitted } 
from '../../../../core/store/policy/policy.selectors';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { QueueCartItem, AdditionalInterests } from 
'../../../../core/store/policy/policy.models';
import { QuestionService } from 
'../../../questions/service/question.service';
import { QuestionControlService } from '../../../questions/service/question-
control.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-additional-interests-form-component',
  templateUrl: './additional-interests-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./additional-interests-form.component.scss"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class AdditionalInterestsFormComponent implements OnInit, 
DynamicComponentBase {
  routeAnimationsElements = ROUTE_ANIMATIONS_ELEMENTS;
  @Output() dynamicComponentPayLoad = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();
  @Output() stepperGoBack = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() stepperGoForward = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Input() showBackButton: boolean;
  @Input() extraData: any;
  tab1Name: string = "Policy View";
  tab2Name: string = "Save View";
  tab3Name: string = "Submit View";
  questionKeys: string[] = [];
  additionalInterestsForm: FormGroup;
  formValueChanges$: Observable<AdditionalInterestsFormModel>;
  activeTab: number = 0;
  questions: any[];
  isReadOnly: boolean;
  loadingData$: Observable<boolean> = 
  this.store.select(selectLoadingAdditionalInterest);
  isInCart$: Observable<boolean> = 
  this.store.select(selectIsAdditionalInterestsInCart);
  isSubmitted$: Observable<boolean> = 
  this.store.select(selectIsAdditionalInterestsSubmitted);

  private defaultAdditionalInterestsDetailModel: 
  AdditionalInterestsFormModel;
  private formNames: string[];
  private cart: QueueCartItem[];
  private submittedChanges: QueueCartItem[];
  private additionalInterests: AdditionalInterests;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>,
    private questionService: QuestionService,
    private questionControlService: QuestionControlService) {

    this.store.select(selectPolicyIsReadOnly).subscribe(isReadOnly => {
      this.isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    })

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     let formControl = new AdditionalInterestsFormElements();
     this.formNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(formControl);
     let tempQuestions: any[] = 
 this.questionService.getQuestionsByKeys(this.formNames);
     this.questions = tempQuestions;
     this.additionalInterestsForm = 
     this.questionControlService.toFormGroup(tempQuestions, this.isReadOnly);
  }

   tabChanged($event) {
    //this.buidTabView($event.tab.textLabel);
   }

  goBack() {
    this.stepperGoBack.emit('')
  }

  goForward() {
    this.stepperGoForward.emit('')
  }

  reset() {

  }

  submit() {
    if (this.additionalInterestsForm.valid) {
      this.additionalInterestsForm.markAsPristine();
    }
  }
}
```

the view

```
<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="(loadingData$ | async)" mode="indeterminate"></mat-
progress-bar>
<form [formGroup]="additionalInterestsForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" 
class="additionalInterests">
  <div class="justify-content-center">
    <mat-card class="" [ngClass]="routeAnimationsElements">
      <div fxLayout="column">
        <mat-card-title style="margin-left:50px; margin-bottom:20px;">
           Additional Interests
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>
           <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="activeTab" 
  (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)" color="warn">
              <mat-tab label="{{tab1Name}}">
              <ng-template matTabContent>
                <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="20px" class="fnol-min-widht50">
                  <div *ngFor="let question of questions" style="  width: 40%;">
                     <app-question [question]="question" [formGroup]="additionalInterestsForm"></app-question>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="{{tab2Name}}" [disabled]="!(isInCart$ | async)">
               <ng-template matTabContent>
                <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="20px" class="fnol-min-widht50">
                  <div *ngFor="let question of questions" style="  width: 40%;">
                    <app-question [question]="question" [formGroup]="additionalInterestsForm"></app-question>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label={{tab3Name}} [disabled]="!(isSubmitted$ | async)">
              <ng-template matTabContent>
                <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="20px" class="fnol-min-widht50">
                  <div *ngFor="let question of questions" style="  width: 40%;">
                    <app-question [question]="question" [formGroup]="additionalInterestsForm"></app-question>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>

        </mat-card-content>
      </div>
      <mat-card-actions *ngIf="!isReadOnly">
        <div class="row buttons d-flex" fxLayoutAlign="end">
          <div class="row buttons justify-content-between pad form-container-action-buttons">
            <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="reset()" [ngClass]="routeAnimationsElements">Reset</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [ngClass]="routeAnimationsElements" [disabled]="!additionalInsuredForm.valid||additionalInsuredForm.pristine" (click)="goForward()">SAVE TO QUEUE</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</form>
```

component module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedModule } from '../../../shared';
import { ArchwizardModule } from 'angular-archwizard';
import { DynamicFormQuestionModule } from '../../questions/dynamic-form-
question.module';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AdditionalInterestsFormComponent } from "./additional-interests-
components/additional-interests-form.component";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';

NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdditionalInterestsFormComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [AdditionalInterestsFormComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ArchwizardModule,
    //DynamicComponentLoaderModule.forChild(AddressFormComponent),
    DynamicFormQuestionModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    })
  ]
})

export class AdditionalInterestsFormModule {
  static entry = AdditionalInterestsFormComponent;
}
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(
    http,
    `${environment.i18nPrefix}/assets/i18n/examples/`,
    '.json'
  );
}
```

Comment: Please share the module the component is declared in. Also show the import of the `ReactiveFormsModule`. Did you try to additionally import the `FormsModule`?

Comment: Please share app.module.ts file as well.

Comment: Yes I also import FormsModule. Shared shared.module.ts and app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My component module was missing a "@"

So it was

```
NgModule
```

instead of

```
@NgModule
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not imported `ReactiveFormsModule` in your imports array. You have just added it in exports array.

Comment: It's on line 3 of my shared.module.ts

Comment: I am talking about the imports array where you have the to import the module. The top part is where you are importing from the path, it doesn't add the module.

 Check your imports array line 2 you have imported FormsModule, like that you need to import ReactiveFormsModule.

Comment: I've added it under FormsModule in the imports array but I still get the same error. Also, every other form we have works so I'm still not sure this is the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, now that dependency is aside. Can you show your form's html as well, and the component.ts?

Comment: Also import the Reactive forms module in your each feature module

Comment: What do you mean by the last comment "import the reactive forms module in each of your feature module?"

Comment: Do you have a sub module where you are using this form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217469/discussion-between-soulzityr-and-wahab-shah).